# Android view.getheight() is not giving correct value for first time in onGlobalLayout() method

Tags: android, android-layout

```
View v = viewgroup.findViewById(R.id.gradient);
    v.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            LayerDrawable mLD = (LayerDrawable)v.getBackground();
            mLD.setLayerInset(1, 0, v.getHeight() / 2, 0, 0);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

In this code viewgroup is a relativelayout. It contains a view v. I am applying a gradient over the view. Gradient has 2 items. So i need to get the height of the view and place the items accordingly. `v.getHeight()` is not giving proper result. In this code `onGlobalLayout()` is called only once as i am removing the listener.

If i comment if else part of code,  `onGlobalLayout()` is called multiple times. In that case second time i am getting proper result for `v.getHeight()`.

So anyone knows why i am not getting correct value for the first time call on `onGlobalLayout()` method ?

Comment: Yes. getMeasuredHeight is giving same value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `OnGlobalLayout()`, simply use `View.post()`. In your case like :

```
//The view from which the height is required
View requiredView = findViewById(R.id.your_view);
//This will be added in the runnable Queue
requiredView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void Run() {
        LayerDrawable mLD = (LayerDrawable) requiredView.getBackground();
        mLD.setLayerInset(1, 0, requiredView.getHeight() / 2, 0, 0);
    }
});
```